# node package forever -w not watching file changes

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am using forever node package for running the node application. i have used below command in terminal.

```
forever start index.js -w -l access.log
```

-l for maintaining logs 
-w for watching files changes

But files changes are not deducted.
package.json :

```
{
  "name": "travel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "travel",
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "scripts": {
    "start": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Luxurious",
    "booking"
  ],
  "author": "john",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "^2.2.0",
    "apns": "^0.1.0",
    "app-root-path": "^2.0.1",
    "async-foreach": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "changes are not deducted"?

Comment: it means it must restart the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.

Comment: Try also setting `--watchDirectory`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but still not working.